# How to prevent Angular store dispatch from creating infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngxs

I came across a problem recently and have written a simplified version of it. I was wondering what the best approach was to solve an issue like this. Say you have a simple State with an updateState action and a selector which selects that value from the state like so

```
const defaults: AppStateModel = {
  test: 'test'
};

@State<AppStateModel>({
  name: 'app',
  defaults
})
@Injectable()
export class AppState {

  @Selector()
  static testSelector(state: AppStateModel): string {
    return state.test;
  }

  @Action(UpdateTest)
  updateState(ctx: StateContext<AppStateModel>, { nextTest }: UpdateTest) {
    ctx.patchState({
      test: nextTest
    });
  }
}
```

I then call a function from a component which takes in as an input the async pipe from the selector and then dispatches the action like so.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name">
    <p>Test: {{testFunction(testSelector$ | async)}}</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Select(AppState.testSelector)
  testSelector$: Observable<string>;
  name: string;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
  }

  testFunction(test: string): string {
    console.log("testprint");
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateTest(this.name));
    return test;
  }
}
```

Now this is going to create an infinite loop as the state updates and the component keeps receiving the updated state value, but how would you prevent this from happening? What if I really need the component to call a function with an input from the selector but that function also needs to change the same state?

Comment: What is the meaning of that component? We usually try to avoid writing functions inside templates cause they will get called on every render. You should probably want to use Angular hooks, like `ngOnInit` and get the values inside a variable and set the variable in the template.

Comment: Yea this is a simplified version of the code I'm actually having issues with but that one was a bit long/messy so I tried to dumb it down a bit. I guess then would a solution be to move the selector async pipe call to within the component?

Comment: The answer above is pretty much that you asked I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output of the selector as an action input no worries.  I know it's a contrived example for SO but its a bit unclear as to *when* you want to dispatch the action to mutate the state - it'd be driven off an event or another Observable typically - if you have it in the template then it'll be called on every change detection cycle (which is most certainly not what you want).

Usually you want to trigger the change off some input - then mutate the state via an action.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="nameChanged($event)>
    <p>Test: {{ testSelector$ | async }}</p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Select(AppState.testSelector) testSelector$: Observable<string>;

  name: string;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
  }

  nameChanged(newName: string): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateTest(newName));
  }
}
```